# Convolution integral $\int_0^t \cos(t-s)\sin(s)\ ds$

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, trigonometry, definite-integrals

How can I calculate the following integral?

$$\int_0^t \cos(t-s)\sin(s)\ ds$$

I can't get the integral by any substitutions, maybe it is easy but I can't get it.

Comment: did you try expanding $\cos (t-s)=\cos t \cos s + \sin t \sin s$?

Answer (score 11):

Let
$$
\mathcal{I}=\int_0^t \cos(t-s)\sin(s)\ ds,\tag1
$$
then using property
$$
\int_b^a f(x)\ dx=\int_b^a f(a+b-x)\ dx,
$$
we have
$$
\mathcal{I}=\int_0^t \cos(s)\sin(t-s)\ ds.\tag2
$$
Adding $(1)$ and $(2)$, we obtain
\begin{align}
2\mathcal{I}&=\int_0^t [\cos(t-s)\sin(s)+\cos(s)\sin(t-s)]\ ds\\
&=\int_0^t \sin(s+t-s)\ ds\\
&=\int_0^t \sin (t)\ ds\\
&=\sin(t)\int_0^t\ ds\\
\mathcal{I}&=\large\color{blue}{\frac{1}{2}t\sin (t)}.
\end{align}

Comment: Very nice answer! One of the best in integration here! +1!! d(>‿◠)b

Comment: @V-Moy Thanks! I forgot to mention that
$$
\sin(x+y)=\sin x\cos y+\sin y\cos x,
$$
where we have all known this trig identity.

Comment: small typo in second last line.

Comment: @BennettGardiner Thank you. I've fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you can use the formula $$\cos\phi\sin\psi=\frac{\sin(\phi+\psi)-\sin(\phi-\psi)}2,$$ which should make things easier, since then $$\cos(t-s)\sin s=\frac12(\sin t-\sin(t-2s)=\frac12\sin t+\frac12\sin(2s-t).$$ At that point, you can split the integral into two parts to evaluate separately.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $\cos(t-s)=\cos t\cos s+\sin t\sin s$, so that the integrand becomes
$$\cos(t-s)\sin(s)=\cos t\cos s\sin s+\sin t\sin s \sin s=\left(\frac{1}{2}\cos t\right)\sin 2s+\sin t \sin^2 s$$

You should be able to integrate this.

Answer (score 2):

If you expand the $\cos $ function, you get two integrals, one is of the form
$$
\int \cos s \sin s ds  =-\int \cos s d (\cos s) 
$$
and the other one is 
$$
\int \sin^2 s ds = \int \frac{1- \cos 2 s ds}{2}
$$

which are very simple