# Integral with trig functions and substitution

Tags: calculus

How to integrate: $\int_0^T\cos(T-s)\sin(s)ds$? I was trying to use $\cos(a+b)=\cos a\cos b-\sin a\sin b$ and substitute $\cos(s)=u \Rightarrow \sin(s)ds=du$ but it does't help.

Comment: First of all, if $u = \cos s$, $du = -\sin s ds$.

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
\int_0^T \cos(T-s) \sin s \, ds &= \int_0^T (\cos T\cos s +\sin T \sin s) \sin s \, ds \\
&= \cos T \int_0^T\cos s \sin s \, ds + \sin T \int_0^T \sin^2 s \, ds
\end{align}
For $\int_0^T\cos s \sin s \, ds$, use substitution rule: $u=\cos s$, $du=-\sin s \, ds$

For $\int_0^T \sin^2 s \, ds$, recognize that $\sin^2 s = \frac 12(1-\cos (2s)$ and integrate the latter expression.

Answer (score 1):

Substituting $u=T-s$,

$$I=\int_{0}^{T}\cos{(T-s)}\sin{(s)}\,\mathrm{d}s\\
=\int_{0}^{T}\cos{(u)}\sin{(T-u)}\,\mathrm{d}u\\
=\int_{0}^{T}\cos{(s)}\sin{(T-s)}\,\mathrm{d}s.$$

Adding the first and last lines,

$$2I=\int_{0}^{T}\sin{(T-s+s)}\,\mathrm{d}s\\
=\int_{0}^{T}\sin{(T)}\,\mathrm{d}s\\
=\sin{(T)}\int_{0}^{T}\,\mathrm{d}s\\
=T\sin{(T)}.$$

Hence,

$$I=\frac12 T\sin{(T)}.$$

Comment: [Convolution integral $\displaystyle\int_0^t \cos(t-s)\sin(s)\ ds$](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/813987/123277).